# Comparing values of a single column of pandas dataframe in python (transforming perl to python code)

Tags: python, pandas, perl, dataframe

I am trying to convert a perl code to python for simple multiplications of columns by some constants.
I've created a pandas dataframe with multiple columns of float values.
Here is the example of the components.csv file.

```
      NA  MULT   NOA   NOB  CHARGE   EX
0    8.0   1.0  24.0  24.0     0.0  1.0
1    8.0   1.0  24.0  24.0     0.0  1.0
2    8.0   1.0   6.0   6.0     0.0  1.0
3   20.0   1.0  18.0  18.0     0.0  1.0
4   23.0   1.0  21.0  21.0     0.0  1.0
5   26.0   1.0  24.0  24.0     0.0  1.0
6   11.0   1.0  13.0  13.0     0.0  0.0
7   16.0   1.0  19.0  19.0     1.0  0.0
8    1.0   1.0   4.0   4.0    -1.0  0.0
9   17.0   1.0  23.0  23.0     0.0  0.0
10   1.0   1.0   4.0   4.0     0.0  0.0
11   1.0   1.0   4.0   4.0     0.0  0.0
```

The initial parameters are:

```
$A1 = 9.3692400791;
$A2 = 9.4492960287;
$B  = 3.8320915550;
$C  = 9.5936653352;
$D  = 1.8739215238;
$E  = 2.4908584058;
```

The expected output is a single column (d5):

```
Df5
-0.2249
-0.2249
-0.0562
-0.1686
-0.1968
-0.2249
-0.1218
-0.1780
-0.0384
-0.2155
-0.0375
-0.0375
```

After parsing into a dataframe by using:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 8)
df = pd.read_csv("unscaled_components_delimit.csv", delimiter= ",", header=0)
```

I've got multiple conditions to check, for example the following script:

```
if (df['NA'] > 1).any():
    print(True)
elif (df['NA'] == 1).any():
    print(False)
```

However the code above, prints only a single value of True, even though there are multiple values of 1.0 at the column with header NA, that means that it does not pass to the second elif. I used the function any() , and maybe another function should be used which I am currently not aware of.
Hence, might someone suggest a solution for that?

The goal, is to compare each element of column (header NA) with number 1 (larger or equal).
Then, perform some actions with other conditions for the other columns.

I would be grateful for any help or suggestion.

For more clarity, the following code contains the final desired code with all required conditions:

```
if (df['NA'] > 1).any():
    if (df['MULT'] == 1).any():
        if ((df['NOB'] != 1).any() or (df['NOB'] ==1).any()):
            d5 = -A1*df['NOB']
        elif((df['NOB'] == 1).any()):
            d5 = -E*df['NOB']
    else:
        d5 = -A2*df['NOB'] - B*(df['NOA']-df['NOB'])

elif (df['NA'] == 1).any():
    if (df['MULT'] == 1).any():
        if ((df['EX'] == 0).any() and (df['NOB'] == 4).any() and (df['CHARGE'] == 0).any()):
            d5 = -A1*df['NOB']
        elif((df['NOB'] != 1).any() or ((df['NOB'] == 1).any() and (df['EX'] != 0).any() )):
            d5 = -C*df['NOB']
        elif((df['NOB'] == 1).any() and (df['EX'] == 0).any()):
            d5 = -E*df['NOB']
    else:
        d5 = -C*df['NOB'] - D*(df['NOA']-df['NOB'])
```

The original perl code is the following ($nh is not needed, hlc in perl is the d5 in python):

```
 if ($na > 1) {
                    if ($mult == 1) {
                            if (($nob != 1) || (($nob == 1) && ($nh != 0))) {
                                    $hlc = -$A1 * $nob;
                            }
                            elsif (($nob == 1) && ($nh == 0)) {
                                    $hlc = -$E *$nob;
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                            $hlc = -$A2 * $nob - $B * ($noa - $nob);
                    }
            }

            ### HLC for atomic species ###
            elsif ($na == 1) {
                    if ($mult == 1) {

                            if (($ex == 0) && ($nob == 4) && ($charge == 0)) {
                                    $hlc = -$A1 * $nob;
                            }
                            elsif (($nob != 1) || (($nob == 1) && ($ex != 0))) {
                                    $hlc = -$C * $nob;
                            }
                            elsif (($nob == 1) && ($ex == 0)) {
                                    $hlc = -$E *$nob;
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                             $hlc = -$C * $nob - $D * ($noa - $nob);
                    }
            }
```

Comment: This code has many errors. Could you show what your expected output is?

Comment: Thanks, I added the expected output.

Comment: In your code, you write `if ((df['NOB'] != 1).any() or (df['NOB'] ==1).any()):`, and then `elif((df['NOB'] == 1).any()):`. The `elif` will never trigger, did you intend to use `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: Are you aware that this makes no sense?=   `if ((df['NOB'] != 1).any() or (df['NOB'] ==1).any()):
            d5 = -A1*df['NOB']
        elif((df['NOB'] == 1).any()):
            d5 = -E*df['NOB']`

Comment: On top of the logical errors, are we certain that the boolean expressions have been reduced/simplified as much as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Denver already explained why your comparisons on the NA column are not returning what you expect.

However, I would do the comparisons differently than he did. Here is a little snippet that should help your understanding:

```py
# a series of bools, indicating for which index our condition is true
na_gt_1_series = df["NA"] > 1
print(na_gt_1)

# creating a new column based on the values of the NA column
df["na_gt_1"] = na_gt_1_series
print(df)
```

---

Now, since the conditions here are quite complex, I think it would be simpler to use pandas' apply function, which applies a function along a certain axis of a DataFrame.

```py
def get_row_df5(row):
    df5 = 0
    if row["NA"] > 1:
        if row["MULT"] == 1:
            if row["NOB"] == 1:
                df5 = -A1 * row["NOB"]
        else:
            df5 = -A2 * row["NOB"] - B * (row["NOA"] - row["NOB"])
    elif row["NA"] == 1:
        if row["MULT"] == 1:
            if row["EX"] == 0 and row["NOB"] == 4 and row["CHARGE"] == 0:
                df5 = -A1 * row["NOB"]
            elif row["NOB"] != 1 or row["NOB"] == 1 and row["EX"] != 0:
                df5 = -C * row["NOB"]
            elif row["NOB"] == 1 and row["EX"] == 0:
                df5 = -E * row["NOB"]
        else:
            df5 = -C * row["NOB"] - D * (row["NOA"] - row["NOB"])
    return df5

df5_res = df.apply(func=get_row_df5, axis=1)
```

---

Unfortunately, that simplicity comes at a cost. For a 120,000-row DataFrame, made by duplicating your example data, the apply solution takes ~4s, versus ~40ms (100x faster) for the following solution.

```py
def get_df5_broad(df_in):
    na_lt_1 = df_in["NA"] > 1
    na_eq_1 = df_in["NA"] == 1
    mult_eq_1 = df_in["MULT"] == 1
    mult_ne_1 = ~mult_eq_1

    res_series = pd.Series(np.zeros(shape=df_in.shape[0]))

    res_series.loc[na_lt_1 & mult_eq_1 & (df_in["NOB"] == 1)] = -A1 * df_in["NOB"]
    res_series.loc[na_lt_1 & mult_ne_1] = -A2 * df_in["NOB"] - B * (df_in["NOA"] - df_in["NOB"])
    res_series.loc[na_eq_1 & mult_eq_1 & (df_in["EX"] == 0) & (df_in["NOB"] == 4) & (df_in["CHARGE"] == 0)] = -A1 * df_in["NOB"]
    res_series.loc[na_eq_1 & mult_eq_1 & ((df_in["NOB"] != 1) | ((df_in["NOB"] == 1) & (df_in["EX"] != 0)))] = -C * df_in["NOB"]
    res_series.loc[na_eq_1 & mult_eq_1 & (df_in["NOB"] == 1) & (df_in["EX"] == 0)] = -E * df_in["NOB"]
    res_series.loc[na_eq_1 & mult_ne_1] = -C * df_in["NOB"] - D * (df_in["NOA"] - df_in["NOB"])

    return res_series
```

---

Finally, this next method is the best of both worlds. It is similar in its design and simplicity to the method using apply, while being only 5 times slower than the previous high-performance version.

```py
def get_df5_tupe(tupe):
    df5 = 0
    if tupe.NA > 1:
        if tupe.MULT == 1:
            if tupe.NOB == 1:
                df5 = -A1 * tupe.NOB
        else:
            df5 = -A2 * tupe.NOB - B * (tupe.NOA - tupe.NOB)
    elif tupe.NA == 1:
        if tupe.MULT == 1:
            if tupe.EX == 0 and tupe.NOB == 4 and tupe.CHARGE == 0:
                df5 = -A1 * tupe.NOB
            elif tupe.NOB != 1 or tupe.NOB == 1 and tupe.EX != 0:
                df5 = -C * tupe.NOB
            elif tupe.NOB == 1 and tupe.EX == 0:
                df5 = -E * tupe.NOB
        else:
            df5 = -C * tupe.NOB - D * (tupe.NOA - tupe.NOB)
    return df5

def get_df5_iter(df_in):
    return pd.Series((get_df5_tupe(curr) for curr in df_in.itertuples(index=False)))
```

Note: these methods do not always return the correct answer due to the logical ambiguities in the OP. I will edit my solution as soon as the right boolean expressions are available.

Comment: I appreciate your answer Alexander, plus I added the expected output. I am waiting for it.

Comment: @Pythonkindergartendeveloper take a look, tell me what you think :)

Comment: Your answer was golden Alexander. All of the best!

Comment: @Pythonkindergartendeveloper you’re welcome, let me know if you have any questions! :)

Answer (score 1):

This block here:

```
if (df['NA'] > 1).any():
    print(True)
elif (df['NA'] == 1).any():
    print(False)
```

Will always print True because the column 'NA' has values greater than 1 and therefore the second elif will not be evaluated. Based on your comments I think you want to loop through the DataFrame and evaluate each element if I am not mistaken. You could try something like this:

```
for val in df['NA']:
    if val > 1:
        print(True)
    elif val == 1:
        print(False)
```

This will evaluate each element of the column 'NA', for your actual use case you will want to know the index of a given val, which can be done using `enumerate`. For example:

```
for (idx, val) in enumerate(df['NA']):
    if val > 1:
        d5 = -A1 * df['NOB'].iloc[idx]
    elif val == 1:
        d5 = E * df['NOB'].iloc[idx]
```

`idx` is the index of the current element, and you can access the element of other columns at that index using `iloc`. I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Denver, I will look into it.