# Lenth of values mismatch using np.where or how to write values based on condition into the new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a df:

```
A | B |
aa| 11|   
aa| 12|    
aa| 13|   
ab| 11|   
ac| 11|
ab| 12|   
ad| 11|   
ae| 11|
```

I'm trying to create third column and fill it depending on the next condition:
IF item in A has value 12 OR 13 - write 'yes in the C column. Else-write no.

So I created empty column C and got the unique A values. And used a for loop to fill the dataframe column, but I constantly get an error.

```
df['C'] =''
uni = df['A'].unique()
for a in uni:
    vals=['12', '13']
    df['C'] = np.where(df[df['A']==a]['B'].isin(vals), 'YES', 'NO')
```

I also tried to use another for loop

```
for a in uni:
 if ('12' in df[df['A']==a]['B'].values) | ('13' in df[df['A']==a]['B'].values):
    df["C"]='YES'
else:
    df["C"]='NO'
```

But in this case the whole column is filled only with NO values.
Where did I turn wrong way?

Comment: IF item in A has value 12 OR 13 , shouldnt be if item in B?

Comment: This other answer of mine might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58401873/11301900. And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58384987/11301900 This is quite a basic pandas question, no doubt been asked hundreds of times before.

Comment: `df['C'] = np.where(df['B'].isin(('12', '13')), 'YES', 'NO')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing values of a single column of pandas dataframe in python (transforming perl to python code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384805/comparing-values-of-a-single-column-of-pandas-dataframe-in-python-transforming)

Comment: @DanielMesejo poorly worded, sorry. I meant if an item in column A has one of specific values in column B => do smth.

Comment: Then I guess @Krrr coment works, no?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using the strings `'Yes'` and `'No'` instead of booleans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first test values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) test if at least one `True` per rows:

```
vals=[12, 13]
df['C'] = np.where(df['B'].isin(vals).groupby(df['A']).transform('any'), 'YES', 'NO')  
print (df)
    A   B    C
0  aa  11  YES
1  aa  12  YES
2  aa  13  YES
3  ab  11  YES
4  ac  11   NO
5  ab  12  YES
6  ad  11   NO
7  ae  11   NO
```

Or get all values `A` per condition, get unique values and pass to another `isin`:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].isin(df.loc[df['B'].isin(vals), 'A'].unique()), 'YES', 'NO')  
print (df)
    A   B    C
0  aa  11  YES
1  aa  12  YES
2  aa  13  YES
3  ab  11  YES
4  ac  11   NO
5  ab  12  YES
6  ad  11   NO
7  ae  11   NO
```

Comment: Yeah I dont get it, this seems right to me. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: thanks! it actually became a surprise to me that no loop is needed...

Comment: @Ison with `pandas` people usually avoid looping as it's slower, and there's almost always a built-in method (or a combination thereof) to achieve the same results.

Comment: @Krrr is right. When working with numpy and/or pandas, loops are a last resort, reserved for weird corner cases.

Comment: bad JS habit with these loops, sorry, guys :$ I'm just in constant learn of all the pandas features

Comment: In row 0 and row 3, shouldn't the value in column C be "no"? 11 != 12 and 11 != 13. @Ison can you confirm that the conditions in your question are correct?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile hi. Sorry for the late reply, I was sure I sent the answer to you question. No, everything is correct since we assign yes/no values to the whole particlar group in column A. Since the group AA has values 12 and 13 in column B  alongside other values, its status in column C is yes. The same is with AB group. So basically the task was not to detect 12 and 13 values in groups, but detect groups that have these values and aggregate theme by assigning common value (yes/no in this case)

Comment: @Ison Ah I see what happened. I misunderstood what you were trying to do based on this sentence in your post: "I'm trying to create third column and fill it depending on the next condition:
IF item in A has value 12 OR 13 - write 'yes in the C column. Else-write no."

Comment: @Alexander Cécile yop, my reason is because OP want it in question.

Comment: @jezrael I meant to comment on the question, sorry!

Answer (score -1):

Please look around on stackoverflow and on the web in general, This sort of question has been asked many times before.

Anyway, onto the code.

```
df["C"] = "NO"
df.loc[(df["B"] == 12) | (df["B"] == 13), "C"] = "YES"
```

For what it's worth, this answer is about twice as fast as the one by @jezrael.

Comment: @Ison does this work? I know it doesn’t write “yes”/“no”, but if those particular values are absolutely necessary it’s a simple tweak. No need to use numpy or anything complicated.